# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I developed a web apps that is working properly when I am running through visual studio 2015. But when I am accessing that web app through IIS, I am getting error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>   )

I tried all possible solutions from Internet.

Here is my web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OnlineLearningConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OnlineLearning.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and code behind of aspx file:

```
protected void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OnlineLearningConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
            SqlDataReader dr;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student where Email = @email and Password = @password", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtboxemail.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Encrypt(txtboxpass.Text.Trim());

            con.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
}
```

I tried to start, stop SQL Server browser, allowing firewall etc. none worked for me.

Event log:

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0 

  - EventID 1309 

   [ Qualifiers]  32768 

   Level 3 

   Task 3 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2018-08-18T07:29:42.000000000Z 

   EventRecordID 31266 

   Channel Application 

   Computer PUNAM-PC 

   Security 


- EventData 

   3005 
   An unhandled exception has occurred. 
   8/18/2018 12:59:42 PM 
   8/18/2018 7:29:42 AM 
   d9f4ba00c0f242538c958820c7d572dd 
   5 
   1 
   0 
   /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/OnlineLearning-1-131790509312759530 
   Full 
   /OnlineLearning 
   D:\project\ 
   PUNAM-PC 

   10720 
   w3wp.exe 
   IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 
   SqlException 
   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details. ) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at css_login.loginbtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\project\login.aspx.cs:line 37 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  
   http://localhost/OnlineLearning/login.aspx 
   /OnlineLearning/login.aspx 
   ::1 

   False 

   PUNAM-PC\PC-PC 
   9 
   PUNAM-PC\PC-PC 
   False 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at css_login.loginbtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\project\login.aspx.cs:line 37 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: *See the Windows Application event log for error details* - have you checked it? might be permissions issue.

Comment: How to check that

Comment: [How to Check the Application Event Log for Errors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769(v=exchg.65).aspx)

Comment: Checked...no error details found

Comment: There should be. anyway, to me it looks like a permissions issue. The IIS user doesn't have enough permissions

Comment: Everything is working perfectly.But when I am clicking LogIn button then getting error

Comment: Ofcourse, that's where you are trying to open a connection. I strongly recommend you to get back to event viewer and find that error

Comment: I updated Event log

Comment: Are you sure the `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` exists on the target machine?

Comment: If that  not exists in my machine then I should get error while running through visual studio

Comment: But through visual studio its running perfectly without any issue

Comment: Do you use development machine for deployment?

Comment: Yes, IIS is installed on the same machine

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 The obvious differences are there. The application pool identity is something you should check, as it cannot access your database right now.

Comment: I tried that answers which you marked as duplicate. But does not help me